# How to Slice character and display in HTML file in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I have below string which i am displaying in HTML file from Api response.

**For ex -** Test,Abc,Red,blue,Green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
displayFull() {
   this.enumValues = this.fullText;
} 

getData() {   
  this.service.getDetails(this.id).subscribe((response: any) => {
    if (response && response.data) {
    this.fullText = response.data; // declare fullText on the top of the class else this will show error.
    this.enumValues = this.fullText.length > 10 ? this.fullText.slice(0, 10): this.fullText; // Add "+ '...'" if you want to add eclipses.
  }
});
```

}

in HTML

```
<p class="break-word-text">
   {{enumValues}}
</p>
<a href="#" *ngIf="enumValues !== fullText" (click)="displayFull()">View More</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<p class="break-word-text" >
    <span *ngIf="enumValues && enumValues.length > 10">{{enumValues.slice(0, 10)}} <a href="#" title="{{enumValues}}">View more</a></span>
    <span *ngIf="enumValues && enumValues.length <= 10">{{enumValues}}</span>
</p>
```

Comment: its not working for me bcz i am getting values in an array like ["Red,Blue,ABC,Test1,RENT,YES,NO"]